# Number of solution of $x^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ where $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and p is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

This question is to be used in a theorem of Algebraic Number Theory and I am struck on this.

> Question: Prove that there are 2 solutions of the equation $x^2 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ . Here $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and p is a prime.

By Euler's criteria, −1 is quadratic residue. So, solution of the equation exists mod $p$. But I am not able to prove that only two solutions exists.

Can you please tell which result should I use?

I have studied elementary number theory from David Burton.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not true. For $p=21$, the equation has no solution.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: Considering $p$ a prime. If $x$ is one of the solution then $-x$ is also a solution. And since $x^2+1$  being viewed  as a polynomial(of degree 2) over a field($\Bbb Z_p$) it can have at most 2 roots.

Comment: In a field any polynomial of degree $n$, can have at most $n$ solutions.  $Z_p$ is a field,  assuming $p$ is prime.  Also $p>2$, so if $a $ is solution then $-a$ is another solution

Comment: If $a$ is a solution, then $x^2+1\equiv x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a)$ is divisible by $p$. This happens if and only if one $x-a$ or $x+a$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime, $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field hence $x^2+1$ can at most have $2$ roots. It is well known that in the case $p\equiv 1\mod 4$, $x^2+1$ has a solution and if $u$ is one solution , $-u$ is the other. Since $p$ is an odd prime, the solutions cannot coincide. Hence, we have exactly $2$ solutions.

Comment: Why are there so many answers in the comments ?

Comment: @Peter I suggest that you write an answer of this comment so that I can accept it.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Ya, p is a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field so, $x^2+1 $ can have atmost 2 roots. Atleast 1 root exists by Euler's Criterion of Quadratic Residues and it x is given a solution, then -x is also a solution  and if x=-x , then this implies that 2x=p or 2|p but p is prime , so $x\neq -x$. So, exactly 2 roots exists.